# Why ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statement increase value by 2 instead of 1?

Tags: mysql, insert

What would cause ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statement to increase value by 2 instead of 1, 
here is SQL im using:

```
INSERT INTO banner_view (banner_id,date,views) 
VALUES ('10',CURDATE(),'1')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE views=(views+1)
```

Here is Database Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `banner_view` (
`banner_id`  int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
`date`  date NOT NULL ,
`views`  int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`banner_id`, `date`),
FOREIGN KEY (`banner_id`) REFERENCES `banner` (`banner_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
UNIQUE INDEX `banner_id` USING BTREE (`banner_id`, `date`)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci
ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT
;
```

I have checked MySQL log to insure that query is called exactly 3 times, but the output will be 6, what can be wrong?

UPDATE:
this method is called inside smarty template like:
{app_banner::getRandomBanner()}

Comment: What output is 6? Where do you get that output from? What query are you doing to get the output? Is this being called from PHP? Can you post a more complete code example?

Comment: Im checking directly in database, and value would be always double from expected

Comment: Works correctly here. `views` is `3` after running query three times

Comment: Why do you have both `PRIMARY KEY` and a `UNIQUE` index on the same set of fields?

Comment: i have removed unique index from table properties, but it is not related to this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silver Light is correct, you are calling the code twice. If you are not doing it explicitly in the code, i.e.:

```
inc3x();
inc3x();
```

Then perhaps you are loading the page twice. This can happen if you include an empty src in the document. Example:

```
<script src=""></script>
```

Use the browser to check all the resource files being loaded.

Comment: You are right, there was empty source inside image tag and mod_rewrite was loading default index page that contained banners.

Comment: I had a bug exactly like this once. And like you I looked and looked at my sql statement thinking, "This just cannot happen this way!" Glad it worked out.

Comment: The empty source inside the image tag causes the browser to download the page again as an image. It does not parse it like html.

Answer (score 2):

Check if you are not calling query twice in your code - it works as expected by itself.

Answer (score 1):

The only reason this query would be increasing the values by more than one would be if it's getting called more than once.  Put an `echo ('<p>Query being run</p>')` into your code at the point where the query is being invoked.  You should see it once, if you see it more than once then the code is being run more than once.

Interactive debugging could also prove quite helpful in this kind of situation, if you have a debugging module such as xdebug installed you can use it to single step through the code and see exactly what it's doing.

Answer (score 1):

Any chance there are any [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-triggers.html) on the table?

```
SHOW TRIGGERS LIKE 'banner%'\G
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact issue, and narrowed it down to the following CSS code:

```
body {
   background-image:url();
}
```

If no image URL is specified for `background-image`, it causes the entire page to reload in some browsers (as documented [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=473528)).  I had the problem with Chrome (v23), but not IE 10.